# Changing wp_insert_post() location

Tags: wp-insert-post

I know that `wp_insert_post()` insert posts into `wp_posts` table. I want to change that to insert posts into lets say `wp_posts2`. Can I do that?

I need to do this because I don't want to mess data from 2 databases and I barely use them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is theoretically possible. While there is no explicit way to do this in post insert/update process, all queries go through `query` filter before being run on database.

Practically this is a no go. The level of complexity in WP's handling of post querying is incomprehensible and full of edge cases. There is no easy telling how much would break over *seemingly* simple tweak of having more than one posts table. There *are* solutions and people doing this, but this is always driven by heavy operation requirements (elaborate content management needs, database sharding for performance and so on).

In a nutshell as question posed — leave it alone before you mess up much more than you want to avoid there. :)